# stl(libcxx) renderers in Xcode debug

Tags: xcode, macos, lldb, libc++

The test case is simple: just std::vector with some elements. During debug session I do not see even the size of the vector, which according to lldb is 0.

I have googled a lot and what I only found out that lldb using libcxx.py script to make debugging developer friendly:

```
def update(self):
    logger = lldb.formatters.Logger.Logger()
    try:
        self.start = self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('__begin_')
        self.finish = self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('__end_')
        # the purpose of this field is unclear, but it is the only field whose type is clearly T* for a vector<T>
        # if this ends up not being correct, we can use the APIs to get at
        # template arguments
        data_type_finder = self.valobj.GetChildMemberWithName(
            '__end_cap_').GetChildMemberWithName('__first_')
        self.data_type = data_type_finder.GetType().GetPointeeType()
        self.data_size = self.data_type.GetByteSize()
    except:
        pass
```

This looks outdated and feels to me like a huge amount of work to polish everything in this script for all containers. I cannot believe that there is so much pain in 2018 :(

The header of this python script also says:

> ships with current releases of OS X - They will not work for other implementations
>   of the standard C++ library - and they are bound to use the
>   libc++-specific namespace

Perhaps there is a version of the macOS which is shipped with compatible libc++ and formatters?

now I'm on macOS 10.13.4, Xcode 9.4.1 and I need c++17 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stl data formatters were moved from python based to built-in C++ ones a while back.  The current vector one is here, if you are interested:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/source/Plugins/Language/CPlusPlus/LibCxxVector.cpp

The Python versions were left as examples of what you can do in a data formatter.

I don't have a 9.4 easily available, but I tried the 10.0 beta and lldb prints std::vectors correctly when compiled with -std=c++17.  If that's not your experience, please file a bug either with http://bugreporter.apple.com or http://bugs.llvm.org with the example that's failing for you.